# Insert a list to another list with index for each of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two list

```
a=[1 2 3]
b=[4 5 6]
```

The result I want is

```
a=[1 4 5 6 2 3]
```

I have a code like

```
position=1
for i in range(len(a))
    a.insert(i+position, test2)
```

However, the result is

```
>>>a=[1 [4 5 6] 2 3]
```

Now the index 1 is [4 5 6], it should be only 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to go is definitely Cyttorak's answer but if you want to know what is wrong with your code, it should be:

```
a=[1, 2, 3]
b=[4, 5, 6]
position=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.insert(i+position, b[i])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use indexing:

```
>>> a[1:1] = b
>>> a
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Will this one work if I want to insert at multi-locations, like indexes 1 and 2.

Comment: @Miraboreasu what's your expected output?

Comment: Because when the 456 is plugged into the index 1, the index sequence changes. Just for an example, my expected output is [1 4 5 6 2 4 5 6 3]

Comment: I see, in that case assign to index `2` first. i.e. `a[2:2] = b; a[1:1] = b`

Comment: Thank you, I want to know does this method works when I am using ```for index, (num1, num2) in enumerate(zip(x,x[1:]))```, assume x=[1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3], I want to plug zero into index 2 and 4, which are the latter number is smaller than the previous number

Comment: Well, it's hard to say without knowing your expected output. For example, if you want `[1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3]` of course possible, but if you want `[1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 2 3]`, there would be some extra steps.  e.g. https://pastebin.com/acWZZxej . Also I would suggest asking a separate question with your exact requirement, you would get more appropriate and better quality answers.

Comment: pastebin.com/acWZZxej works well, I also wonder how to turn the whole idx (in your code) into a float, and using ```x[i:i]=0```, I tried float(), but it cannot be applied to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over the range with the length of the list, you can get that that index and insert that into a

```
a=[1 ,2, 3]
b=[4, 5 ,6]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.insert(i+1, b[i])
print(a)
```